# in tensorflow, how do I convert a list of indices to an indicator vector?

Tags: python, tensorflow

My input are lists of indices like

```
[1,3], [0,1,2]
```

how can I convert them into fixed length indicator vectors?

```
[0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import tensorflow as tf

indices = [[1, 3, 0], [0, 1, 2]]
many_hot = tf.one_hot(indices, depth=4)
many_hot = tf.reduce_sum(many_hot, axis=1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(many_hot))
```

This prints

```
[[1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0.]]
```

Note that this only works if all the indices have the same amount of indices in each entry of the list. If this is not the case, you could do it with a loop:

```
import tensorflow as tf

indices = [[1, 3], [0, 1, 2]]
many_hots = []
for idx in indices:
    many_hot = tf.one_hot(idx, depth=4)
    many_hot = tf.reduce_sum(many_hot, axis=0)
    many_hots.append(many_hot)

many_hot = tf.stack(many_hots)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(many_hot))
```

This prints

```
[[0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0.]]
```

Comment: Just as a comment for the future, TensorFlow 2.x will support [ragged tensors](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensors), so it might be possible to do this for different number of indices without looping.

Comment: thanks for the solution, do you think `tf.math.bincount` will also help?

Comment: @dontloo Yes, good point actually. You could replace the first two lines in the loop with `many_hot = tf.math.bincount(idx, minlength=4, maxlength=4)`. I don't know if there is a difference in performance. Also, I think `bincount` can only produce output tensors of rank 1, so you will need to use the loop variant even if `indices` technically could be a tensor.